# How to understand the salesforce platform point and click features

Tags: framework

I am new to Salesforce, having a good experience in development on mainframes,I want to learn Salesforce to support a project in months to come,I want to understand how to identify that for a particular situation one has to do custom coding, i mean are there any documents/sites which can help to demonstrate the boundary conditions?

Regards,
Tushar

Comment: You should work through the [Force.com Workbook](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) in order to understand how the platform works along with the limitations on what you can do with point & click. This is the way most devs learn the platform. Then do the Process Builder Trailhead module.

Answer (score 1):

hi there check this link : https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiSos6bwKLMAhXLKZQKHQ3oBb0QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fhelp%2Fpdfs%2Fen%2Fsalesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHFJHr5-kl7jtJDbnATdtT9uvfh9Q&bvm=bv.119745492,d.dGo

this is pdf of all the limitations of salesforce. hope it will help you to understand the limitations.

following are some situations where u will need a custom coding :

-> if u dont want the salesforce standard layout and u want your designed page you have to code for that.

-> salesforce provides the limited standard object but if u need your custom object u can create by going to -> objects page. and salesforce provides the click and create objects. just select, fill details, next, finish.. as simple as that.

->salesforce provide different layouts for different user hierarchy like CEO can see other layout, and end user can see different.

-> salesforce also provides following security levels  :

Organization Security,
Object Security,
Record Security,
Field Security,
Folder Security

you will learn this in salesforce trial-heads : https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/trail/force_com_dev_beginner

this link is for beginners to start with salesforce give it a try.

Thank you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/45020)

Comment: just edited my answer hope it will help you. take trial-heads so u can understand more about salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with [Salesforce Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en) and the [Salesforce Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=salesforce_help_map.htm&language=en_US)

Trailhead will give you a good idea of what Salesforce can do and how to do it.  The documentation gives you some pretty good details and specifics.

The first thing I would recommend you do is read up on Security. The Organization Wide Defaults (OWD), Profiles, Roles and how this all related to security in Salesforace.  Also read up on controlling access Field Level Security, Page Layouts, and Record Types.  This will give you a good idea of how to keep things secure, and prevent people from seeing what the shouldn't see or don't need to see.  And Validation Rules too.

For Automation you should read up on [Workflow Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workflow_Rules) and [Field Updates](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_field_update_considerations.htm&language=en), as well as [Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_overview.htm) and [Flows](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/18/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.pdf), and [Approval Processes](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=what_are_approvals.htm&language=en).

There is a lot that Salesforce can do without having to resort to code. Custom code usually comes into play under one of two circumstances.

1. Visualforce Pages & Controllers for when you need your screens to have custom logic/functionality, callouts to other services and advanced displays.
2. Triggers for when you need advanced business logic for updating records or advanced validations.